# How can noise be good?

Tags: noise

It seems like (controlled) noise can sometimes be good: dithering in an image, or a softer sound in audio, or white noise alone. [Here's a paper](http://www.ele.uri.edu/faculty/kay/New%20web/downloadable%20files/00809511.pdf) on noise improving detectability. My intuition also says that noise in a financial trading algorithm could act as a sort of hedge.

I have few examples — only a vague philosophical instinct. Is there any general-purpose literature or theory on why and how noise can be good? Or other/better examples?

Comment: because it reduces distortion http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/19451/29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another example is setting up A/D converters - usually the input is set so that the noise just trips the least significant bit (LSB) of the converter. The noise can also be added manually - this process is also referred to as Dithering. The white papers at various A/D manufacturers can be quite useful e.g. Linear Technologies, Analog Devices and Texas Instruments.

Another term you may wish to look under is Stochastic Resonance.

Comment: Wow, "stochastic resonance" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_resonance) is exactly what I was looking for — I was actually thinking about resonance in the back of my mind. So your answer resonated very strongly with me thanks to a little creative leap you made, which seems like a great example of stochastic resonance!

Comment: @Toph In the paper by Kay (the one you linked to) -  he does mention Stochastic Resonance, so you may find additional references at the end of his paper.